# Transforming a Pandas datafrom based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
    order_id    product_id
0   2           33120
1   4           28985
2   4           9327
3   7           45918
4   14          30035
```

I would like to transform or create a new dataframe where all of the product_id's for each order_id are in the same row. And eventually write to a csv.

```
    product_id1 product_id2 ...
0   33120
1   28985       9327
2   45918
3   30035
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a `pivot` problem , you just need `cumcount` create the key

```
newdf=df.assign(key=df.groupby('order_id').cumcount()).pivot('order_id','key','product_id').fillna('')
newdf
Out[124]: 
key             0     1
order_id               
2         33120.0      
4         28985.0  9327
7         45918.0      
14        30035.0      
#newdf.to_csv('your.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, though less ideal that @W-B's, is to use `apply`:

```
df.groupby('order_id')['product_id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack()

                0       1
order_id                 
2         33120.0     NaN
4         28985.0  9327.0
7         45918.0     NaN
14        30035.0     NaN
```